# c++ - having trouble with writing in the file (ofstream)

Tags: c++, fstream, ofstream

I am trying to write something on the file. But its just not writing as it must suppose to.

```
void main()
{
    int accno;
    char name[20];
    float deposit;

    clrscr();

    ofstream writefile("icici.txt");

    cout<<"enter your saving bank account number";
    cin >> accno;

    writefile << name << endl;

    cout<<"\n\nYour good name:";
    cin >> name;
    writefile << name << endl;

    cout<<"\n\nKey in recent deposit in Rs:";
    cin >> accno;

    writefile << deposit << endl;

    writefile.close();

    cout << "\n\nFile is created successfully...\n\n" << endl;
    ifstream readfile("icici.txt");
    readfile >> accno;
    readfile >> name;
    readfile >> deposit;
    cout<<"\nContent of file is icici.txt is read as follows:\n";
    cout<<"\nSaving bank account number:"<<accno<<endl;
    cout<<"\nCustomer name smt/shri:"<<name<<endl;
    cout<<"\nDeposit amount in Rs:"<<deposit<<endl;
    getch();
}
```

And it writes in the file is like so:

```
99
Mak
3.780703e-42
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's the expected result?

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings and carefuly look at the line following the prompt to enter the deposit amount.

Comment: Line 14, `writefile << name << endl;` name is unitialized.

Comment: `cin >> accno;` appears 2x. You want `cin >> deposit` second time.

Comment: OMG, I am really sorry my bad! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the incorrect variable names and using variables before they've been read and initialized.

This line `writefile << name << endl;` needs to follow `cin >> name;` In your code, it proceeds it and that means name doesn't contain anything or maybe junk data.

I think these lines

```
cout<<"\n\nKey in recent deposit in Rs:";
cin >> accno;
```

Should be:

```
cout<<"\n\nKey in recent deposit in Rs:";
cin >> deposit;
```

Answer (score 1):

At the first `writefile<<name<<endl`, `name` field is undefined. May be would you like to write `accno` instead of `name` ?